# C++ - Display continuously updating image

Tags: c++, user-interface, opencv, directx

I have written a pathtracer in C++, and now I want to display the rendering process in real time, so I'm wondering what the simplest/best way to do this is.

Basically, the rendered image updates after every iteration, so I just need to retrieve it, display it in a separate window, and update it.

I was thinking about using DirectX, and it seems that I could probably also do it with OpenCV, but I'm just looking for a simple way which doesn't require adding a lot of new code.

I am using C++ on Windows.

Comment: I did something similar with opengl and opencl.

Comment: Is it a 2D or 3D path tracer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your path tracer probably outputs a color per emitted ray? If that is the case, and you are thinking about displaying the rendered image in a separate window I'd suggest using [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/). There's a great set of tutorials concerning real-time graphics using C++ and SDL by [Lazy Foo' Productions](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php#Hello%20SDL).

Excerpt taken from official SDL [documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/) (without cruft needed to initialize windows) regarding SDL_Surface, which you will probably be using:

```cpp
/* This is meant to show how to edit a surface's pixels on the CPU, but
   normally you should use SDL_FillRect() to wipe a surface's contents. */
void WipeSurface(SDL_Surface *surface)
{
    /* This is fast for surfaces that don't require locking. */
    /* Once locked, surface->pixels is safe to access. */
    SDL_LockSurface(surface);

    /* This assumes that color value zero is black. Use
       SDL_MapRGBA() for more robust surface color mapping! */
    /* height times pitch is the size of the surface's whole buffer. */
    SDL_memset(surface->pixels, 0, surface->h * surface->pitch);

    SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);
}
```